# gimme-aws-creds tool error occurred (InvalidIdentityToken) when calling the AssumeRoleWithSAML operation: Specified provider doesn't exist

Tags: aws-cli, gimme-aws-creds

Following error message started to pop up while using gimme-aws-creds tool with Okta.

```
Failed to generate credentials for arn:aws:iam::???:role/Here-ADMIN due to An error occurred (InvalidIdentityToken) when calling the AssumeRoleWithSAML operation: Specified provider doesn't exist (Service: AWSOpenIdDiscoveryService; Status Code: 400; Error Code: AuthSamlManifestNotFoundException; Request ID: 3b4ab9b0-c050-4c5a-bf8b-1cade4a6b71e; Proxy: null)
aws_access_key_id is not set None in credentials! dict_keys([])
aws_secret_access_key is not set None in credentials! dict_keys([])
aws_session_token is not set None in credentials! dict_keys([])
```

Does anybody has idea where to look for solution?